# Pdb error while debugging python app with serverless launched offline

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, serverless

I have problem with debugging my view function with 
`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`
placed inside it and serverless launched as
`> sls offline start`
in console.
Namely, making correspondent GET request I receive the following error:

```
Python: > /.../handler.py(88)get_results()
-> request_params = event.query_params


Python: (Pdb)


Python: 2019-02-20 18:37:43,648 [ERROR] | ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ".../handler.py", line 88, in get_results
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 51, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 70, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

Google suggests that the problem is in the inability of serverless process to read from stdin, but I don't know how to handle this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I usually import the handler in a REPL session and execute the functions that way. Have you tried something similar?

Comment: I’m sorry, I didn’t understand that. I run `sls offline star`. handler.py is invoked by sls.  How do you import the handler? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: `cd` to the directory where you have your `handler.py`, run `python` to start an interactive REPL session, do `import handler` and then execute `handler.get_results()` or whatever function you need to. HTH

Comment: It is not always a good idea as `get_result(event, context)` function depends on two variables and we should pass there some values. It would be handy to get that values from the actual http request rather than invent something. Besides, I have more complex situation where the function `get_result` is wrapped by decorator and actual arguments of my function are transformed into some classes instances. So, your approach doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26975795/4388451:

1. create two fifos:

   mkfifo fifo_stdin
   mkfifo fifo_stdout

in one terminal

2. In the same terminal open `stdout` on background, and write to `stdin`:

   cat fifo_stdout & cat > fifo_stdin
3. In python code create the the `pdb` object, and use it:

   import pdb
   mypdb = pdb.Pdb(stdin=open('fifo_stdin', 'r'), stdout=open('fifo_stdout', 'w'))
   ....
   mypdb.set_trace()
4. Run python code from the folder where fifos were placed (or place fifos in the first step in the folder with python code) in another terminal

Now I am able to use `pdb` in first console!

PS 
It is useful to use `--noTimeout` option while debugging:  `sls offline --noTimeout`