# Odoo.sh Editor on Jupyter : pdb.set_trace raises BdbQuit Error

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter, pdb, odoo.sh

Using my odoo.sh project (v13.0.2) > EDITOR-Tab , which redirects me to mywebsite.odoo.com/odoo-sh/editor/lab, when i want to debug using import pdb; pdb.set_trace(), it raises a BdbQuit Error :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 113, in 
  dispatch_exception
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
```

In the past versions : v13.0.1.xxx, i could use pdb.set_trace() to debug my python code. How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rpdb** is a remote debugger based on pdb. It re-routes stdin and stdout to a socket handler, so that you can debug server processes (remotely).

In Odoo.sh > yourstagingBranch, click on the **SHELL**-tab:

```
mywebsite-oerp-staging-5070461 [staging/v13.0]:~$ pip3 install rpdb
```

In Odoo.sh > yourstagingBranch, click on the **EDITOR**-tab:

**IN ODOO-EDITOR:**

- At the top of your python file, add:

```py
    import rpdb
```

- In the function (def subscribe) to be inspected, add:

```py
    def subscribe(self, event, **post):
        # code before
        rpdb.set_trace()
        # code after
```

- Click on menu Tab : Odoo>Update current module : alternatively, open a new Terminal window and execute this command: odoo-bin -u website_sale --stop-after-init

```
    mywebsite-oerp-staging-5070461 [staging/v13.0]: odoo-bin -u website_sale --stop-after-init
```

- After having restarted Odoo (all modules loaded), execute this command in the other Terminal window: nc 127.0.0.1 4444

```
    mywebsite-oerp-staging-5070461 [staging/v13.0]: ~$ nc 127.0.0.1 4444
```

- We can then use the common pdb commands:

**l(ist)**: Lists the lines surrounding the current line

**w(here)**: Displays the file and line number where we currently are

**s(tep)**: Step into the function at the current line

**n(ext)**: Continue execution until the next line in the current function is reached or it returns. (The difference between next and step is that step stops inside a called function, while next executes called functions at (nearly) full speed, only stopping at the next line in the current function.)

**a(rgs)**: Print the argument list of the current function

**p(rint) variablename** : Print value of variablename

**quit** : To quit rPdb

More info : https://itnext.io/debugging-your-code-in-python-pdb-vs-rpdb-e7bb918a8ac3
Official documentation (commands) : https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

#######

OR, alternatively : Using this post [How to debug python CLI that takes stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074177/how-to-debug-python-cli-that-takes-stdin/26975795#26975795) :

1. in Odoo.sh>EDITOR (Jupyter Lab): Open a first Terminal and create these two fifos which will be used as stdin/stdout to use pdb :

   ```
    mkfifo fifo_stdin

    mkfifo fifo_stdout

    cat fifo_stdout & cat > fifo_stdin
   ```

...which makes appear a prompt cursor. Keep this Terminal Tab opened.

2. Write these 2 lines at the top of the Python script to be debugged :

   ```
    import pdb
    mypdb=pdb.Pdb(stdin=open('fifo_stdin','r'), stdout=open('fifo_stdout','w'))
   ```
3. In this Python script, call set_trace() on your customized mypdb:

   ```
   def _get_total_amount(self):     
      total_amount = sum(self._get_base_order_lines(program).mapped('price_total')) 
      mypdb.set_trace()  
      return total_amount
   ```

...