# Check argparse.ArgumentTypeError

Tags: python, pytest, argparse

I want to use `pytest` to check if the `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` exception is raised for an incorrect argument:

```
import argparse
import os
import pytest


def main(argsIn):

    def configFile_validation(configFile):
        if not os.path.exists(configFile):
            msg = 'Configuration file "{}" not found!'.format(configFile)
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
        return configFile

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--configFile', help='Path to configuration file', dest='configFile', required=True, type=configFile_validation)
    args = parser.parse_args(argsIn)


def test_non_existing_config_file():
    with pytest.raises(argparse.ArgumentTypeError):
        main(['--configFile', 'non_existing_config_file.json'])
```

However, running `pytest` says `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` and consequently the test fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `parser._get_value` method catches the `ArgumentTypeError` and raises a `ArgumentError`.  That is turn is caught in `parse_known_args` which exits via `parser.error`.  System unittest file, `test_argparse.py` subclasses `ArgumentParser` to redefine the `error` method.

Comment: Note that `_get_value` also catches `TypeError` and `ValueError`.  The difference is that the `ArgumentTypeError` `msg` is passed on up to the error message, while the others use a standardized message. So a full test would need to check the message content as well as the  `exit`.

Comment: Related question (for `unittest` instead of `pytest`, but similar approach I guess): [How can I test whether my code is throwing the appropriate argparse exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40898755/1804173)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that if argument's type converter raises exception `ArgumentTypeError` `agrparse` [exits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#invalid-arguments) with error code 2, and exiting means raising builtin exception `SystemExit`. So you have to catch that exception and verify that the original exception is of a proper type:

```
def test_non_existing_config_file():
    try:
        main(['--configFile', 'non_existing_config_file.json'])
    except SystemExit as e:
        assert isinstance(e.__context__, argparse.ArgumentError)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Exception not raised")
```

Comment: Does the 2nd `raises` test do anything in this context?

Comment: @hpaulj Good catch! The case is complex. The code have to catch `SystemExit` and verify that the original exception is of `ArgumentTypeError`. I updated the answer. And found that the real exception is of `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Just to add, if you want to verify an error message such as if you provide a wrong choice to an argument that specified choices, you can check against `err.__context__.message`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `ArgumentTypeError` test in the `test_argparse.py` file (found in the development repository)

`ErrorRaisingAgumentParser` is a subclass defined at the start of the file, which redefines the `parser.error` method, so it doesn't exit, and puts the error message on `stderr`.  That part's a bit complicated.

Because of the redirection I described the comment, it can't directly test for `ArgumentTypeError`.  Instead it has to test for its message.

```
# =======================
# ArgumentTypeError tests
# =======================

class TestArgumentTypeError(TestCase):

    def test_argument_type_error(self):

        def spam(string):
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('spam!')

        parser = ErrorRaisingArgumentParser(prog='PROG', add_help=False)
        parser.add_argument('x', type=spam)
        with self.assertRaises(ArgumentParserError) as cm:
            parser.parse_args(['XXX'])
        self.assertEqual('usage: PROG x\nPROG: error: argument x: spam!\n',
                         cm.exception.stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pytest` you can do the following in order to check that `argparse.ArugmentError` is raised. Additionally, you can check the error message.

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as e:
    main(['--configFile', 'non_existing_config_file.json'])

assert isinstance(e.value.__context__, argparse.ArgumentError)
assert 'expected err msg' in e.value.__context__.message
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Giorgos's answer, here is a small context manager that makes the message extraction a bit more re-usable. I'm defining the following in a common place:

```py
import argparse
import pytest
from typing import Generator, Optional


class ArgparseErrorWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._error: Optional[argparse.ArgumentError] = None

    @property
    def error(self):
        assert self._error is not None
        return self._error

    @error.setter
    def error(self, value: object):
        assert isinstance(value, argparse.ArgumentError)
        self._error = value


@contextmanager
def argparse_error() -> Generator[ArgparseErrorWrapper, None, None]:
    wrapper = ArgparseErrorWrapper()

    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as e:
        yield wrapper

    wrapper.error = e.value.__context__
```

This allows to test for parser errors concisely:

```py
def test_something():
    with argparse_error() as e:
        # some parse_args call here
        ...
    assert "Expected error message" == str(e.error)
```