# Python unittest does not take passed parameters

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, python-unittest

I have following code:

```
class WebuiSeleniumTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup_parser(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Automation Testing!')
        parser.add_argument('-p', '--platform', help='Platform for desired_caps', default='Mac OS X 10.9')
        parser.add_argument('-b', '--browser-name', help='Browser Name for desired_caps', default='chrome')
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', default='')
        return parser.parse_args()

    def test_parser(self):
        args = self.setup_parser()
        print args


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When i try to run this in terminal with the command "python myfile.py -b firefox" I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'firefox'` and the help output is generated.
When I isolate it and run it without the `if __name__ == "__main__"` it works fine. Why does it try to apply my passed argument on unittest ? I need it as a String in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your script with `python myfile.py -b firefox` does indeed go to unittest, and not to your argument parser.

Unittest tries to parse the arguments you gave, e.g. if you call your script like this:

```
python myfile.py --help
```

You see the valid options:

```
Usage: myfile.py [options] [test] [...]
Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs
Examples:
  parse.py                               - run default set of tests
  parse.py MyTestSuite                   - run suite 'MyTestSuite'
  parse.py MyTestCase.testSomething      - run MyTestCase.testSomething
  parse.py MyTestCase                    - run all 'test*' test methods
                                               in MyTestCase
```

Looking at the help output `-b` would buffer (I guess suppress?) stdout/stderr. The argument `firefox` is taken as the name of the test to run in your module. And there is no function `method` existing, it outputs this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'firefox'
```

Now, what you probably want to do is to call `test_parser`, and if you do that with `python myfile.py WebuiSeleniumTest.test_parser` then you cannot pass any additional arguments. And that's probably your question in the end. There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module) which gives some possible solutions for testing argparse as unit test.

Comment: Great answer, not only answering my question but even teaching me where  I went wrong. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you and have a great weekend !