# How to give arguments for argparse without the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a program that takes 2 ints as arguments and everything works as expected in the command line. I want to be able to create a tester python file that imports this first program, calls program.main(), and pass along two ints as arguments for main. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you write tests for the argparse portion of a python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module)

Comment: Unfortunately no since I cannot edit the first program and argparse is called through program.main()

Comment: You can assign to `sys.argv` before calling `program.main()`

Comment: It's inelegant, but could you just set a new value for `sys.argv` ?

Comment: `argparse` unittest tests both methods - passing an argv argument, and tweaking the sys.argv list.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to `sys.argv` before calling `program.main()`

```
import sys
import program

sys.argv = ["program.py", "1", "2"]
program.main()
```

Comment: I think the program name is typically the firs argument of `argv` isn't it

Comment: `sys.argv[1:= ['1','two']` would be better.  But look at `sys.argv` first just to safe.

Comment: @hpaulj That's wrong because we want to emulate what would happen when you run `program.py`. The current `sys.argv` contains the name of the testing script.

Comment: Thr only differenece will be  the displayed name in the usage.

Comment: @hpaulj Although uncommon, the application can examine `sys.argv[0]` and change its behavior depending on it. In any case, there's no reason for it to be different from what it would be if you ran executed the script normally.