# Write tests for the argparse module in Python but 'TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Tags: python, typeerror, argparse, python-unittest

I want to use 'argparse' library to get the arguments from the command line in my program. Everything is working well when I run the script, but I have a problem to write proper unit tests for that piece of code to prove that everything is working fine.

I get the TypeError that I do not understand why it appears when I test my parser:

```
TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I wrote my code, basing on this: [How do you write tests for the argparse portion of a python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module)

My ArgParser class:

```
class AppArguments(NamedTuple):
    device_name: str
    start_date: str
    end_date: str

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):

        arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description="Description.")

        arg_parser.add_argument(
            '-d', '--device',
            nargs=1,
            help="Device name.",
            metavar='DEVICE_NAME',
            required=True
        )
        arg_parser.add_argument(
            '-s', '--start',
            nargs=1,
            help="Starting date.",
            metavar='YEAR-MONTH-DAY',
            required=True
        )
        arg_parser.add_argument(
            '-e', '--end',
            nargs=1,
            help="Ending date.",
            metavar='YEAR-MONTH-DAY',
            required=True
        )

        arg = arg_parser.parse_args()

        return cls(device_name=arg.device, start_date=arg.start, end_date=arg.end)


def main():

    arg = AppArguments.create()

    print(arg.device_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My UnitTestClass:

```
import unittest


class AppArgumentsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_device_with_time(self):
        # given
        arguments = AppArguments.create(['-d', 'test_device', '-s', '2022-08-11', '-e', '2022-08-12'])

        # then
        self.assertEqual('test_device', arguments.device_name)
        self.assertEqual('2022-08-11', arguments.start_date)
        self.assertEqual('2022-08-12', arguments.end_date)
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my testing class or how can I make it work?

Comment: Well, you're passing an argument to `AppArguments.create`. But that method doesn't accept any arguments (besides the implicit `cls`).

Comment: When I run tests with empty arguments:

`    def test_with_empty_input(self):
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
            AppArguments.create()
            self.assertEqual(cm.exception, "Error")`

I got the error `the following arguments are required: -d/--device, -s/--start, -e/--end`, so I have no idea how I should pass them to meet the requirement.

I used similar arg parses class in my other scripts and tests were working as written above, no TypeError... Hmmm...

Comment: Well, your `create` method is just calling `parse_args` with no arguments meaning it tries to get the arguments to parse from `sys.argv` (see the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args). That doesn't really make sense in a test does it? Why don't you pass the strings to `create` and then use them in the call to `parse_args`? That way you're actually testing your parser.

Comment: In a unit-test framework you can't supply the `argparse` command line values the same way as you do when the running the script by itself.  Unittesting of a parser is tricky, and has been discussed in a  number of SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
arguments = AppArguments.create(['-d', 'test_device', '-s', '2022-08-11', '-e', '2022-08-12'])
```

You're *passing* arguments to `AppArguments.create` here. So that method must accept the arguments here:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, args):
                ^^^^
```

And then you want to pass those arguments on to `parse_args` here:

```
arg = arg_parser.parse_args(args)
                            ^^^^
```

If you want to be able to call `AppArguments.create` with or without arguments (in the latter case you'd want the argument parser to implicitly use the arguments passed on the command line), make `args` optional:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, args=None):
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that's because you set `required` arguments of `arg_parser.add_argument()` to `True`, then you should provide them when you call the method `parse_args()` of `arg_parser`.
Example of usage:

```
#1
arg_parser.parse_args(['--device', 'name', '--start', '1', '--end', '2'])
#2
arg_parser.parse_args('--device name --start 1 --end 2'.split())
```

If you didn't set argument `required=True` then you are not required to provide them when you call the method `parse_args()`.

I suggest you to read [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) on python 3 docs