# How to test command line applications in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line-interface, python-3.6, python-unittest

I know Python `unittest`. I have some experience using it for testing Python subprograms.

Now I need to add testing my command line application (*not* just a Python function) written in Python. I want to call it with certain arguments and certain input in stdin and test output in stdout.

How to integrate testing a command line tool with other `unittest` test cases?

Or what to use instead of `unittest`?

Comment: sounds like a validation or integration tests, could be implemented with any languages, python unittest should be fine with it.

Comment: > _"Or what to use instead of unittest?"_ see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13493288/a#70888702 . Also noticed the use of `self.assertEqual`, `self.assertIn`, ... in accepted answer? that's why `pytest`'s doc says under [features](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/#id1) : _"no need to remember `self.assert*` names"_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can still use the standard `unittest` format and test the whole application as a standard function. Make a wrapper that makes the script entry point a simple wrapper, like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

As long as you don't abuse global variables for keeping the state, you only need to test the `main()` function.

If you want to test scripts which you don't have control over, you can still use `unittest` and `subprocess` by writing a test like:

```
def test_process(self):
    result = subprocess.run(['your_script', 'your_args', ...], capture_output=True)
    self.assertIn('expected out', result.stdout)

def test_process_failure(self):
    result = subprocess.run(['your_script', 'your_args', ...], capture_output=True)
    self.assertEqual(result.returncode, 1)
```

Comment: I thought about this. But are there other ways? (I want it to work with all kinds of Python scripts, not only scripts done with the guidelines which you gave in your answer.) Just to make sure.

Comment: @porton added an example for testing scripts from outside

Comment: ahw right, `self.assertEqual`, `self.assertIn`, ... - that's why `pytest`'s doc says under [features](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/#id1) : _"no need to remember `self.assert*` names"_