# how to test python file with pytest having if __name__ == '__main__': with arguments

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a python file with pytest which contains a `if __name__ == '__main__':`
it also has arguments parsed in it.
the code is something like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Execute job.')

    parser.add_argument('--env', required=True, choices=['qa', 'staging', 'prod'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # some logic
```

The limitation here is I cannot add a `main()` method and wrap the logic in `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside it and run it from there!
The code is a legacy code and cannot be changed!

I want to test this with pytest, I wonder how can I run this python file with some arguments inside my test?

Comment: What if your test found a bug? Would you not be able to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668947/3141234

Comment: And if you can't change it, there's no point writing tests for it. Either you verify it works using ad-hoc, one-time tests and you never need to run further tests again, or you verify it doesn't work and you have to replace it with something that *does* work (and can be properly tested).

Comment: this is thoughtful but not answering my case, of course I will change the code if a bug found or if I have to. But question here is if it is possible to have such a test case which is running the file from its entry phase with arguments defined.

Comment: Then consider the lack of a `main` function a bug, and fix it.

Comment: @Alexander patching the arg could be helping but how to run the file from entry phase?

Comment: @chepner I will ultimately have to do this if I couldn't find another answer, honestly I am a bit curious to see if there is anyway doing this. At the end it can be a good learning thing.

Comment: You might be able to do something with `with open("script.py") as f: exec(f.read())`, but I would sooner fix the file than mess with `exec`.

Comment: This answers your question -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736889/13261176

Comment: thanks @TeejayBruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line arguments are an input/output mechanism like any other. The key is to isolate it in a "boundary layer", and have your main program not depend on them directly.

In this case, rather than making your program access `sys.argv` directly (which is essentially a global variable), make it so your program is wrapped in an "entry point" function (e.g. "main") that takes args as an explicit parameter.

If you don't pass any arguments to [`ArgumentParser.parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args), defaults to accessing `sys.argv` for you. Instead, just pass along your `args` param.

It might look something like:

```py
def main(args):
    # some logic
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.arv)
```

Your unit tests can call this entry point function and pass in any args they want:

```
def test_main_does_foo_when_bar():
   result = main(["bar"])
   assert "foo" == result
```

Comment: What about test coverage though? (on `if __name__ == '__main__':` line)

Comment: problem is I cannot change this python file, it is part of a legacy code and cannot not be changed!

Comment: good point @Tibebes.M, there should be a way to add coverage tests for this part of the code as well!

Answer (score 0):

Generally I make a `main` function which always takes arguments and call it with command line arguments when needed.

```
def main(args):
    # parser : argparse.ArgumentParser
    args = parser.parse_args(args)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

When run from command line it will be called with command line arguments. It can be called at anytime by calling `main` directly.

Comment: Problem is I cannot change the file to include a main() method and call this method from my test code